# Why is the html content I got from inspector different from what I got from Request?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Here is the site I am trying to scrap data from:
[https://www.onestopwineshop.com/collection/type/red-wines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQjEh.png)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://www.onestopwineshop.com/collection/type/red-wines"
response = requests.get(url)
#print(response.text)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,'lxml')
```

The code I have above.

It seems like the HTML content I got from the inspector is different from what I got from BeautifulSoup.
My guess is that they are preventing me from getting their data as they detected I am not accessing the site with a browser.  If so, is there any way to bypass that?

---

(Update) Attempt with selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
# start web browser
browser=webdriver.Chrome(path)
#navigate to the page
url = "https://www.onestopwineshop.com/collection/type/red-wines"
browser.get(url)
# sleep the required amount to let the page load
time.sleep(3)
# get source code
html = browser.page_source
# close web browser
browser.close()
```

---

Update 2:(loaded with devtool)
[image]

Comment: "My guess is that they are preventing me from getting their data as they detected I am not accessing the site with a browser." No. The site, like most modern websites, loads content dynamically using Javascript after the initial HTML loads. In order to access that content you need a browser with a Javascript engine; you can't get it with a basic HTTP client like `requests`.

Comment: The inspector shows the DOM after JavaScript has updated it dynamically. `requests.get()` just returns the original HTML, which you can see if you use `View Source` in the browser.

Comment: @larsks fair point, but actually wrong. Most data comes from fetch requests. So you can very well get the content by querying this : https://api.commerce7.com/v1/product/for-web?&collectionSlug=red-wines - beautifulsoup is not needed, requests + json will do fine.

Comment: In some cases it's possible to identify specific resources you can request directly. In other cases it's not. The point remains that you won't get that content by requesting the main page, and you know that's not actually wrong.

Comment: From "you can't get it with a basic http client" we get to "in some case...". Hate to repeat it but yes you were wrong, it is perfectly possible to get the data the OP needs with just HTTP requests, that's just a fact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any website with content that is loaded after the inital page load is unavailable with BS4 with your current method. This is because the content will be loaded with an AJAX call via javascript and the `requests` library is unable to parse and run JS code.

To achieve this you will have to look at something like `selenium` which controls a browser via python or other languages... There is a seperate version of selenium for each browser i.e firefox, chrome etc.

Personally I use chrome so the drivers can be found here...

https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

1. download the correct driver for your version of chrome
2. install selenium via pip
3. create a `scrape.py` file and put the driver in the same folder.

then to get the html string to use with bs4

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time

# start web browser
browser=webdriver.Chrome()
#navigate to the page
browser.get('http://selenium.dev/')
# sleep the required amount to let the page load
time.sleep(2)
# get source code
html = browser.page_source
# close web browser
browser.close()
```

You should then be able to use the `html` variable with BS4

Comment: I have updated the post with my attempt with selenium and it is still giving me the same content, any idea what I can do?

Comment: Just figured out I could increase the time in sleep and it successfully gets the content I need.  Tysm!!

Comment: Stupid solution, you could just query the server directly.

Comment: @Loïc ? can you give some examples

Comment: just did below : ```curl 'https://api.commerce7.com/v1/product/for-web?&collectionSlug=red-wines' -H 'tenant: one-stop-wine-shop'``` there are two more urls you can query to get all data as json, so no need for js. I'll let you convert that to requests if you feel like testing...

Answer (score -3):

I'll actually turn my comment to an answer because it is a solution to your problem :

As other said, this page is loaded dynamically, but there are ways to retrieve data without running javascript, in your case you want to look at the "network" tab or your dev tools and filter "fetch" requests.

This could be particularly interesting for you : [image]

You don't need selenium or beautifulsoup at all, you can just use `requests` and parse the json, if you are good enough ;)

There is a working cURL requests : `curl 'https://api.commerce7.com/v1/product/for-web?&collectionSlug=red-wines' -H 'tenant: one-stop-wine-shop'`

You get an error if you don't add the `tenant` header.

And that's it, no html parsing, no waiting for the page to load, no javascript running. Much more powerful that the selenium solution.

Comment: Unsure how devtools will help the op in this situation?

Comment: When the page loads it will send fetch (or ajax) requests to load some data from the server. Using devtools you can sniff those requests, and find what you want.
Then, instead of running js and parsing html, you actually just load the data you are really looking for in sweet json. What don't you get?

Comment: I loaded the site with dev tool on but don't see the page that you got, am I doing something wrong? (Picture in the post)

Comment: Op didnt ask how to manually do anything, he wants to use python, hence downvote.

Comment: @DJ-coding just filter on "fetch" requests and you got them.

Comment: @LewisMorris I've edited my answer to show you that there is nothing to do manually. Please reconsider your vote.